# Can iOS today extension access local storage?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, local-storage, today-extension

I am creating a widget for cordova based iOS app. Can iOS extensions access local storage of the containing app? I have searched a lot but could not come across an answer. All I have understood is app groups can be used to share data. But my main concern is to access local storage data of the app(user credentials of the app basically).

Comment: Did you manage to find any solutions for this?  I've been looking at creating a Today Extension for a Cordova app, but nothing I've found has made me believe that such a thing is technically possible.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access **Containing App's** local storage directly from **Today Extension**.

> Even though an app extension bundle is nested within its containing
>   app’s bundle, the running app extension and containing app have no
>   direct access to each other’s containers.

1. To access any kind of data of **Containing App** from **Today Extension**, you have to use **App Groups**.
2. To share code within **Containing App** and **Today Extension**, use **Framework**.